# How to make an activity transparent and making sure previous activity is blurred?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created an activity transparent which has a layout in the center that is opaque. What I want is the previous activity(which can be seen) should be blurred. I tried opacity but it doesn't really help.

I want to make the transparent layout `parentRelative` blur.

TransparentActivity.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentRelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    tools:context=".TransparentActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondParentRelative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TransparentActivity.java

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentRelative);
    relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                            blur(TransparentActivity.this, captureScreenShot(relativeLayout))));
}

public static Bitmap captureScreenShot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Drawable backgroundDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (backgroundDrawable != null) {
            backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
        }
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
}

public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
    float BLUR_RADIUS = 23f;

    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;
}
```

The `blur` and `captureScreenShot` is something that I tried from some other SO answer. But it is not working.

I want to make the transparent layout blur.

Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: You could rather use 2 fragments and set the background color to translucent for the 2nd fragment so that it works as you want

Comment: How will this ensure burred background? @Kartik

Comment: Fragments stack on one another and you can see that if you do not apply any background color to the parent viewGroup for the 2nd fragment, you will be able to see the whole 1st fragment in the background.

Comment: I can see the first fragment but view behind the fragment is not getting blurred